# WooCommerce delete custom jQuery codes I add to Product Short Description

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing an eCommerce site with WordPress+WooCommerce.

I added buttons to certain products in the Short Description field in order to quickly select certain number of products to be added in the cart (this is because I have different offers, for example: "Buy 4 for the price of 3").

*I have a script like this in the general jquery file:*

```
<script>
    function pack4() { document.getElementById("quantity").value = "4"; }
    function pack8() { document.getElementById("quantity").value = "8"; }
</script>
```

*And this is an example of the code I have in some products Short Description:*

```
<span><strong>4x3 Pack:</strong>TOTAL<strong>$1800</strong></span>
<button class="select" onclick="pack4()">Select</button>
```

Everything works and whenever you click on every button the order quantity adds the corresponding number.

**The thing is:** Whenever my client (who usually edits products) click on the Text/Visual flap of Short Description, the **`onclick="pack4()"`** code disappears. I guess WordPress/WooCommerce have got some jQuery filter that erases this kind of codes. I need it to stop doing that, because the client regularly edits things (and of course they don't know anything about coding). Otherwise, I have to add the code again every time.

I also suspect WP/WC also filters it without needing to click on this Text/Visual flap (but I might be wrong about that).

Anyone knows what to do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest and accurate way is to create a custom shortcode this way:

```
if( !function_exists('display_product_button_pack') ) {

    function display_product_button_pack( $atts ) {

        // Shortcode Attributes
        $atts = shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'pack' => '4', // default pack is 4
            ),
            $atts,
            'button_pack'
        );

        $output = '<button class="select" onclick="pack'.$atts['pack'].'()">Select</button>';

        return $output;

    }

    add_shortcode( 'button_pack', 'display_product_button_pack' );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The code is tested and works.

---

**USAGE:**

There is an optional **`pack`** argument in your shortcode, which default value is **`4`**…

For your **Pack 8** for example, you will insert this in the short description product editor:

```
[button_pack pack="8"]
```

This will output this html:

```
<button class="select" onclick="pack8()">Select</button>
```

For the Pack 4, as default argument value is already 4 you just use this:

```
[button_pack]
```

Comment: Genius, that's perfect, it worked! Solved, thank you very much!